# Unexpected App_Sheet_SelectionChange behavior

Tags: vba

I have a custom menu with two items: "On" and "Off". The "On" item calls an Add-In function to init some functionality (crosshair). After pressing the the "On"  item, I would like to see the crosshair move on each selection change (i.e a click a cell and a the corresponding row/column gets highlighted). Hence, I have implemented something in `Worksheet_SelectionChange()` and turning the feature On makes the code in `Worksheet_SelectionChange()` do something. However, `Worksheet_SelectionChange` is worksheet-specific and I want to use this functionality across sheets without having to add code to each sheet where I want to use the crosshair. So, I reached for Application events. Hence, I declare

```
Public WithEvents App As Application 

Public Sub Auto_Open()
   Set App = Application
End Sub  

Private Sub App_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
   Call DrawCrossHair(...)
End Sub
```

All is cool as long as I don't click out of Excel into another application. Once that happens, `App` gets reset to `Nothing` and `App_SheetSelectionChange` does not get called as Auto_Open does not get called on each `"Excel_getFocus"`. How can I prevent this reset of App? Or am I using the wrong tool (App Events) for what I want to achieve?

Many thanks, 
Daniel